# Accessing Public sub in ThisWorkbook module

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code in the Sheet1 module and I want to call a sub procedure in that Sheet1 module when the workbook open so I do:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Call MyMacro
End Sub
```

behind SHeet1 I have

```
Public Sub MyMacro()
........
End Sub
```

When the workbook opens I get the error:

sub or function not defined "call GetReutersData"

How can I call MyMacro from the Open() event?

I need to have the MyMacro code in the sheet1 module just becuase that's the way it has to be. I cannot create a new module.

Comment: I would guess that `MyMacro()` is properly being called from `Workbook_Open()` and that somewhere in `MyMacro()`, you have a call to a sub called `GetReutersData`. `GetReutersData` is the one it cannot find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 sheet1.MyMacro
End Sub
```

Comment: The use of 'Call' is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this 
Write the below code in Thisworkbook

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call Sheet1.MyMacro
End Sub
```

'----- Sheet 1 Code ---

```
 Public Function MyMacro()
  MsgBox "hi"
 End Function
```

Is Absolutely Working on My system